# Unable to figure out bundle install error

Tags: ruby, bundler

I recently replaced my XCode 14.3 installation with XCode 15.  I tried to re-clone a repo (to start fresh) and ever since I'm unable to run `bundle install`.

It seems to fail when it tries to delete the directory associated to `json-2.6.3`, but I can't figure out how to fix it:

```
Installing json 2.6.3 with native extensions
Installing unf_ext 0.0.8.2 with native extensions
Installing ffi 1.14.2 with native extensions
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Installing excon 0.104.0
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
9:  excon (0.104.0) from /Users/273663872/.gem/specifications/excon-0.104.0.gemspec
Bundler::InstallError: Bundler::DirectoryRemovalError: Could not delete previous installation of `/Users/273663872/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/json-2.6.3`.
The underlying error was Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ apply2files -  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2342:in `unlink'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2342:in `block in remove_file'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2347:in `platform_support'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2341:in `remove_file'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2330:in `remove'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1470:in `block in remove_entry'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2393:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1468:in `remove_entry'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1383:in `remove_entry_secure'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler.rb:332:in `rm_rf'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:111:in `strict_rm_rf'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:20:in `install'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:203:in `install'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in `do_install'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

Bundler Error Backtrace:
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:115:in `rescue in strict_rm_rf'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:110:in `strict_rm_rf'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:20:in `install'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:203:in `install'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in `do_install'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Users/273663872/.gem/gems/bundler-2.4.20/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing json (2.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
      algoliasearch was resolved to 1.27.5, which depends on
        json
```

I've researched this for hours and can't figure out the solution.  I seem to keep finding articles on StackOverflow that point to the Command Line tools not being installed, but they are already installed on my system.

I'm currently using this Ruby version:
`ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]`

When I go to the `~/.gem/gems` directory, I don't even see `json-2.6.3` listed there, so I'm not sure what `DirectoryRemovalError` even means.

Can someone please help me fix this? I'm simply trying to run `pod install`, but it seems I have to install some gems through `bundle install` first.

Answer (score 0):

Install Command Line Tools:

`xcode-select --install`

you can try rebuild bundle install

`gem update --system && gem install bundler`

`rm Gemfile.lock`

`bundle install`

Clear Gem Cache:

`gem cleanup`

Comment: I tried `gem cleanup` first, followed by the other steps and it still doesn't work:

```bundle install
....
Installing json 2.6.3 with native extensions
Installing unf_ext 0.0.8.2 with native extensions
Installing ffi 1.14.2 with native extensions
Bundler::DirectoryRemovalError: Could not delete previous installation of `/Users/273663872/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/json-2.6.3`.```